# Error 424 Object needed - Cant seem to find the error

Tags: vba, excel

i am farly new to VBa and am trying to learn by building or replicating existing vba sheets.
In this one, i am getting an error in the following code:

```
Private Sub lstLookup_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
'declare the variables
Dim cPayroll As String
Dim I As Integer
Dim findvalue
'error block
On Error GoTo errHandler:
'get the select value from the listbox
For I = 0 To lstLookup.ListCount - 1
    If lstLookup.Selected(I) = True Then
        cPayroll = lstLookup.List(I, 1)
    End If
Next I
'find the payroll number
Set findvalue = Sheet2.Range("F:F").Find(What:=cPayroll, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, -3)
'add the database values to the userform
cNum = 21
For X = 1 To cNum
    Me.Controls("Reg" & X).Value = findvalue
    Set findvalue = findvalue.Offset(0, 1)
Next
'disable adding
Me.cmdAdd.Enabled = False
Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = True
'error block
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler::
MsgBox "An Error has Occurred  " & vbCrLf & "The error number is:  " _
       & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
       "Please notify the administrator"
End Sub
```

It is giving me the error :" 424 Object required"

i cant seem to find the error

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing is to `Dim findvalue As Range`. Don't leave blank because that sets it to Variant, which may or may not be what you intended. Otherwise, what line does your code error on?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, the error apears in:
'disable adding
Me.cmdAdd.Enabled = False
Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Me.cmdAdd.Enabled = False
Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = True
```

to

```
Me.Controls("cmdAdd").Enabled = False
Me.Controls("cmdEdit").Enabled = True
```